# new Date() function is giving an unwanted Date String

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am using a function to create a Data object using new Date() function as,

```
var a = new Date();
```

It gives me a string like "2016-08-26T08:45:50.408Z" in some case, and this in most cases --> "Thu Aug 25 06:57:10 PDT 2016". I want to know why is there such a difference. Please suggest some method to solve this. I want the format to be only in  "2016-08-26T08:45:50.408Z". Thanks

Comment: How are you getting hold of those strings?  That's where the difference lies.  `a` itself is just a `Date` object - a moment in time, it has no intrinsic format.

Comment: Like say, I use the variable "a" in a JSON object for my purpose. So at time I get this format "Thu Aug 25 06:57:10 PDT 2016".

Comment: Use the [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method when converting the Date object to a string. Using an old browser without this method, then load [`ES5-shim`](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) first. If you are relying on JSON to do the stringify then consider loading [`JSON3`](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3) to fix any bugs.

Comment: you can use `moment` to make it as your requirement `http://momentjs.com/`

Comment: I tried using this, var createdDate = moment().subtract(60, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this-

`moment("Thu Aug 25 06:57:10 PDT 2016").toISOString();`

`output`: `"2016-08-25T13:57:10.000Z"`

Answer (score 1):

Use `a.toISOString()` method. It will give you the expected format.
You can read more about the method here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment. Older browsers (and even some newer ones, including versions of Nodejs) behave in non-standard manners.

1. Use [ES5 shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) to add or fix missing methods
2. Use [JSON3](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3) to add or fix JSON methods

These are available a node modules.

```js
var a = new Date();
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

```html
<script href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.9/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I won't be able to use shim in my code Base. Sorry!

Comment: But you are able to use momentjs??

Comment: Yeah!. Because that's allowed. :)